# Hide Site Settings & Site Contents from Gear Button in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I want to show "Site Contents" and "Site Settings" options in the Gear button only to admins and not from any other users.

[image]

For achieving this, I tried Changing permission string value from viewformpages  to  ManageWeb, managepermissions etc. By doing this its not working for Home page, but is working fine in other site pages.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom Permission levels without  the base permission "View Application Pages", Then assign the non-admin users with the custom permission levels.

Or, you can use JSOM code to check current user's permissions, then hide the two options based on the permission. Note: you need to add your code into master page.